# How to use result of INSERT statement in other INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In **PostgreSQL** database I have 2 tables.

**QUESTIONS**

```
| question_id | question_text | widget | required | position |
|-------------|---------------|--------|----------|----------|
| int         | text          | int    | boolean  | int      |
```

**FACTORS_QUESTIONS_RELATIONSHIP**

```
| factor_id   | question_id   |
|-------------|---------------|
| int         | text          |
```

As you can see in this function I have 2 insert statements. First one return list of ids of new questions. I want to use that ids in the second insert statement. How to make it correctly? In the same time I want to return ids from first statement as result of the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factorio(
    FACTOR_IDENTIFIER INT,
    TEXT_ARR VARCHAR[],
    WIDGET_ARR INT[],
    REQUIRED_ARR BOOLEAN[],
    POSITION_ARR INT[]
) RETURNS SETOF INT AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY
        WITH RESULT_SET AS (
            INSERT INTO QUESTIONS (TEXT, WIDGET, REQUIRED, POSITION) 
            SELECT 
                UNNEST(ARRAY[TEXT_ARR]) AS TEXT,
                UNNEST(ARRAY[WIDGET_ARR]) AS WIDGET,
                UNNEST(ARRAY[REQUIRED_ARR]) AS REQUIRED,
                UNNEST(ARRAY[POSITION_ARR]) AS POSITION
            RETURNING ID
        )
        --
        INSERT INTO factors_questions_relationship (FACTOR_ID, QUESTION_ID) 
        SELECT FACTOR_IDENTIFIER FACTOR_ID, QUESTION_ID FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[array_agg(SELECT ID FROM RESULT_SET)]) QUESTION_ID
        --
        SELECT ID FROM RESULT_SET;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. it looks like there's no need to create a [temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550480/how-to-use-result-of-insert-statement-in-other-insert-statement/55550781#55550781). You can just directly return the result of the `returning id` from return query, even if your second insert statement is dependent on the returned ids of first statement. And it's safe since the resulting_rows is not run twice even it is referenced twice in the query.

Anyway, you might still want to use the temporary table approach if the succeeding statements/queries are complex ones, e.g., using loops. Cannot embed loops in CTE.

```
create or replace function insert_multiple_test()
returns setof int
as           
$$   
begin
    return query
    with resulting_rows as
    (
        insert into z(question_text) values
        ('hello'),
        ('你好'),
        ('hola')
        returning id
    ),
    generate_question as 
    (
        insert into q_factory(q_id, some_text)
        select id, q.another
        from resulting_rows
        cross join unnest(array[
           'answer to life and everything', 
           'are multiple and awesome'
        ]) as q(another)                
    )
    select id from resulting_rows;

end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Test:

```
select * from insert_multiple_test() as x(the_id);
```

Proof that resulting_rows is not run twice even it is referenced twice in the query. It's still 3 rows:

[image]

Test:

```
select * from q_factory;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would just put the ids on temporary table of ids first. Then issue another insert. Then return the temporary table of ids.

Here's an example:

### DDL

```
create table z
(
    id int generated by default as identity primary key, 
    question_text text not null
);

create table q_factory
(
    id int generated by default as identity primary key, 
    q_id int not null references z(id),
    some_text text not null
);
```

### Function

```
create or replace function insert_multiple_test()
returns setof int
as           
$$   
begin
    create temporary table x_t on commit drop
    as
    with resulting_rows as
    (
        insert into z(question_text) values
        ('hello'),
        ('你好'),
        ('hola')
        returning id
    )   
    select id from resulting_rows;

    insert into q_factory(q_id, some_text)
    select id, q.another
    from x_t
    cross join unnest(array[
        'answer to life and everything', 
        'are great and awesome'
    ]) as q(another);

    return query select id from x_t;        
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql'
```

Test:

```
select * from insert_multiple_test();
```

Output:

[image]

Test:

```
select * from q_factory;
```

Output:

[image]